# Striping souble quotes in teradta

Tags: oracle, teradata, informatica-powercenter

I Need to strip the double quotes in my data in teradata while exporting the data into csv file or loading the data into another table say for example,

**actual result**
 PRODUCT_DESC
"TRADE" FULL LINE  GC5/GF/176

**expected result**
 PRODUCT_DESC
TRADE FULL LINE  GC5/GF/176

I need to strip the double quotes and load it to the flat file in informatica too is there any option to strip double quotes?

Comment: You can use the `replace()` function; but are you sure you want to strip them, rather than say escaping them - is the aim just not to confuse Excel or some other program that has to handle the CSV later?

Comment: Is this regarding the data or file header? Have you been trying to adjust the target file properties in "Optional Quotes" section?

Comment: Thank for ur reply,i have been tried otranslate,oreplace and regexpression these are working fine and iam able to strip the double quotes say for example "aaa",dddd" i need this data as aaa, dddd i achieved this by using above formulas

Comment: @Maciejg this is about data not file header thank for ur reply

Comment: but now iam facing the issue while running the query in teradata while iam executing below 
//sel otranslate(product_desc,'"','') as product_desc  from lme_tables_tst.wo_orders//
iam getting the following error
****the string contains the untransalatable character****

Comment: If it's about the data, the `replace()` function mentioned by @AlexPoole should to the trick.

Comment: yeah that got resolved by using replace function but now iam facing with a error mentioned in the above comment ****the string contains the untransalatable character****  can any one help how to  resolve this issue